# AWS: Unable to Launch an Instance from Image created from snapshot

Tags: amazon-web-services

Steps:

```
   1. Create a Snapshot from one of my GP2
   2. Click on Snapshots , select the above snapshot and Click Actions -> Create Image to create Images
   3. Click on AMIs and select the above image and Click "Launch"
```

Landed on Step 2 - Choose an Instance Type. But there are no types available. No valid instance types found. Neither able to click "Review And Launch"

What am I doing wrong?

PS: I can create image from EC2 instance and then able to Launch an instance (shows all types) successfully on that image

Comment: Your old instance maybe EBS -optimized, therefore you can only select specific EBS-optimized instance types. or vice versa

Comment: @jprism which options did you select for `Architecture` and `Virtualization Type`?  The default values are just defaults -- they aren't based on metadata from your snapshot, and some of these attributes determine instance compatibility.

Comment: Haven't chosen anything, just left defaults

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that when you create an `Image (AMI)` from a `EBS snapshot`, the default `virtualisation type` is `Paravirtual.` However, all the `instance types` that I have checked, require `Hardware-assisted Virtualisation.`

So if you click on the `Virtualization type` drop down box and select `Hardware-assisted Virtualisation` as below, then all the types will then be available when you launch an instance from the `ami`.

[image]

**References**

[Linux AMI Virtualization Types](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/virtualization_types.html)
[Launching a Linux Instance from a Backup](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-launch-snapshot.html)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I found that if I create the image from the INSTANCES list, it works fine.

But if I create the image from a snapshot, I get that same error.

Maybe at this time, we simply cannot successfully create images from snapshots - that's my guess. Not the route to go. But I could be wrong.